# Ora2pg FATAL: ERROR: null value in column "entity$code_" violates not-null constraint

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

I'm trying to migrate our DB from oracle to Postgres , after generating the DDL and during insert the Data into Postgres I faced this issue :

```
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] Dumping data from table ACREF_ACCOUNTINGPERIOD_ into PostgreSQL table ACREF_ACCOUNTINGPERIOD_...
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] Setting client_encoding to UTF8...
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] Disabling synchronous commit when writing to PostgreSQL...
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] DEBUG: Formatting bulk of 100000 data (real: 1 rows) for PostgreSQL.
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] DEBUG: Creating output for 100000 tuples
[2020-10-19 18:15:49] DEBUG: Sending COPY bulk output directly to PostgreSQL backend
DBD::Pg::db pg_putcopyend failed: ERROR:  null value in column "entity$code_" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 1395753794346, admin@ALL, 0, null, 1400, com.acf.AccountPeriod, null, null, ALL, user@ALL, false, false, 13000, 753794288, null, null, null, Yearly, true, Current, 873738087).
```

PS: the column entity$code_ have no values with null value,It looks like ora2pg did not migrate all the data
Any help ?

Comment: Postgres can work with identifiers with '$', see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).  In the original table does `entity$code_` have `NULL` values in it? FYI, it is Ora2Pg doing the migration not Postgres.

Comment: thanks for replying , In the original table column entity$code_ have no values with null, so the problem here with ora2pg !

Comment: Then I would file an issue [here](https://github.com/darold/ora2pg/issues).

Comment: I was indicating you should file the issue.